# Escaping front slash inside shell variable value

Tags: string, bash, shell, sed

I am using bash shell script to do certain pattern replacement.
Pattern replacement using `sed` commands to replace one value to another

```
sed/s/abc/$var/g
```

Shell variable `var` contains  path value in shell variable,
e.g `var="dir/abc.txt"`

With shell variable having this value, it causes issue for `sed`.

Idea would be to replace path like this

```
var="dir\/abc.txt"
```

I am using the following function to do the same. This function iterates character by character through string 
and replaces the `/` with `\/`

```
  # This function takes a string and scans for forward slash
    # If forward slash is found , it will replace with escape char.
    # input = "dir/abc.txt
    # output ="dir\/abc.txt
    handle_escape_chars()
    {  
       RETURN_VAL=""
       fileName=$1
       for i in $(seq 1 ${#fileName}); do
          #echo "${fileName:i-1:1}"
          z="${fileName:i-1:1}"
          if [ $z == "/" ];
          then
            z="\/"
          fi
          RETURN_VAL="${RETURN_VAL}${z}"
       done 
       echo $RETURN_VAL
       return
    }
```

Have tried using another alternative, but this did not work

```
fileName="dir/abc.txt"
printf "%q\n" "$fileName"
```

Comment: Why not just change the separator in `sed` from `/` to `#`

Comment: yes . works thanks @Inian . is there solution also to escape the characters inside shell variable ?

Comment: You could use parameter expansion to escape all the backslashes : `${fileName//\//\\\/}`

Comment: @Aaron's answer works well but the last backslash is useless.

Comment: @Diablotin true, I probably escaped the last slash because I'm used to them being a delimiter in `sed` commands.